# Looping through an array to generate a component(undefined array)

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I've got the following object, and trying to loop through the list:

```
  const [object, setObject] = useState({
    answer: {
      [29]: {
        list: [],
      },
    },
  });
```

Now I've got a separate function to loop through the list further down the code, but somehow getting 'undefined' when the page tries to load initially.

```
  const List = object["answer"][29]["list"].map(
    (item, index) => (
      <div> {item.name} </div>
       ...etc
    )
  )
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, I created a [https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-field-4nqhq?file=/src/App.js](codesandbox) with a rough implementation based on the code you shared, along with some dummy data, but I don't think I can reproduce the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the optional chaining operators when working with arrays.

```
object?.["answer"]?.[29]?.["list"]?.map(...)
```

This way it should not crash if the value is not set when loading.

Comment: That worked! Now I'm trying to update the object from a useEffect and I'm seeing the object get updated, but the list doesn't update. Should I create a separate component outside?

Comment: If the answer fits your needs, please accept it. If you have more questions, feel free to open new ones.